# Nodejs Messaging With Express Session

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

Hey guys I am trying to make a messaging system but the problem is when I implement express-session my article post script doesnt works properly.

**This is my express-session middleware:**

```
app.use(session({
  secret:'keyboard cat',
  resave:true,
  saveUninitialized:true,
}));
```

**This is my add article:**

```
app.post('/metin/ekle', function(req, res){
    var metin = new Metin({
      baslik: req.body.baslik,
      yazar: req.body.yazar,
      konu: req.body.konu,
    });

        metin.save(function(err){
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
          } else {
            req.flash('success', 'Metin Eklendi')
            res.redirect("/metin/"+ metin._id)
            res.render('metin_ekle', {
            });
          }
        });
    });
```

When post my articles I get the error of

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client

Comment: Hi Alp Eren i think problem here is you're trying to render metin_ekle page after redirecting to another page.

Comment: Aaaa thanks, such a small mistake causes big errors.

Comment: If you post it for getting like, I would like it

Comment: no ,thank you for your consideration

Comment: But can I ask something ? How to change  div(class="alert alert-"+type) #{message} to alert-dismissible to close the alert

Comment: I tried some but I couldnt do instead of my exact codes

Comment: can you describe it in a new stackoverflow post? i couldn't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Think the alert types of boostrapt. And in my current code I cannot close the alert.(Without refreshing) But I want to make a dissmissible type boostrapt alert which I can close it.